# Complex Analysis Phase Portrait

Tags: complex-analysis

[image][image][image]$$f(z) = {z^5} - {z^4} - z + 1
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamOzaiaacI
% cacaWG6bGaaiykaiabg2da9iaadQhadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaiwdaaaGc
% cqGHsislcaWG6bWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaI0aaaaOGaeyOeI0IaamOEai
% abgUcaRiaaigdaaaa!429B!
$$
[image]

The above is a Phase portrait of f.
The arrow are intended to show two isochromatic lines of yellow meeting at where? 
Since $$f(z) = {z^5} - {z^4} - z + 1 = {(z - 1)^2}(z + 1)({z^2} + 1)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamOzaiaacI
% cacaWG6bGaaiykaiabg2da9iaadQhadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaiwdaaaGc
% cqGHsislcaWG6bWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaI0aaaaOGaeyOeI0IaamOEai
% abgUcaRiaaigdacqGH9aqpcaGGOaGaamOEaiabgkHiTiaaigdacaGG
% PaWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaOGaaiikaiaadQhacqGHRaWkcaaIXa
% GaaiykaiaacIcacaWG6bWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaOGaey4kaSIa
% aGymaiaacMcaaaa!5171!
$$
The zeros should be at 1, -1, i,-i with a double zero at 1 as there are two yellows ending there. But isn't that -1 that's indicated?

Comment: Is it the plot of the phase of $\frac{f(z)}{z^5}$ or $f(1/z)$ ? Because for $f(z)$ we would have $f(z) \sim z^5$ for $|z|$ large so it wouldn't be all red

Comment: Hello, It's the Phase portrait of f(z), where f(z) is as defined above.

Comment: From the book by Elias Wegert called Visual Complex Functions An introduction with Phase Portraits (page 67)

Comment: ?? I have proven it isn't $f(z)$. I'm quite sure it is $f(z)/z^5 = f(1/z)$

Comment: Could the picture have been transposed during publishing so that the double yellows should be on the other side of the page? That is reflected in the vertical-axis? Is the book (see above pp 66-67) wrong?

Comment: 3.5 is $f(z)$ and 3.6 is $f(1/z)$ (with $z=0$ in the middle of both)

Comment: I have hi-lighted the contentious part where Wegert says that the two yellows finish at 1. I see that the canonical form shows that they should be it's the picture that is wrong maybe reflected during typesetting or something? Is this your view do you agree that something is not right? Does the picture show the two yellow lines ending up at -1?